# Update field if value is nil, 0, false in struct golang?

Tags: go, struct, null

I have a struct:

```
type User struct {
   ID       int    `json:"id"`
   Username string `json:"username"`
   About    string `json:"about"`
   IsAdmin  bool   `json:"is_admin"`
   Status   int    `json:"status"`
   ......
}
A:= User{1,"admin", "I am a admin",status: 1,....}
B:= User{ID:1, Username: "UserBBBB"}
...enter code here...
B is {1, "UserBBBB", "I am a admin", 1, ...(same value in A)}
```

object B has a few properties with nil (string), false (bool), 0 (int),...
I want to check if a field of B is unassigned value, that field will receive value of the same field in A,

example:

B's About field is nil;

A's About field is "I am a admin"
I want to B's About field is "I am a admin".

I can write code:

```
if len(B.About) == 0 {
  B.About = A.About
```

}
Similar to other fields, I don't want check step by step with all of fields.

Comment: You probably want to rephrase your question. I read it 4 times, and I still don't know what is your question.

Comment: my question is updated, thanks so much!

Comment: Ok, now I get it. This is feasible, in a generic way, but this will require to use the reflect package. If performance is not an issue for you it may be considered.

Comment: you can help me with a small simple code.  I don't  know how to solve this problem.

Comment: I am currently writing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "reflect"
    "time"
)

type User struct {
    ID       int    `json:"id"`
    Username string `json:"username"`
    About    string `json:"about"`
    IsAdmin  bool   `json:"is_admin"`
    Status   int    `json:"status"`
    Date     *time.Time
}

func main() {
    now := time.Now()
    ua := User{
        ID:       1,
        Username: "admin",
        About:    "I am an admin",
        IsAdmin:  true,
        Status:   1,
        Date:     &now,
    }
    ub := User{
        Username: "user",
    }

    fmt.Printf("ua: %+v\n", ua)
    fmt.Printf("ub: %+v\n", ub)

    err := Replace(ua, &ub)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("\nua: %+v\n", ua)
    fmt.Printf("ub: %+v\n", ub)
}

// IsZeroOfUnderlyingType return wether x is the is
// the zero-value of its underlying type.
func IsZeroOfUnderlyingType(x interface{}) bool {
    return reflect.DeepEqual(x, reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf(x)).Interface())
}

// Replace replaces all fields of struct b that have a
// zero-value with the corresponding field value from a.
// b must be a pointer to a struct.
func Replace(a, b interface{}) error {
    // Check a.
    va := reflect.ValueOf(a)
    if va.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return errors.New("a is not a struct")
    }
    // Check b.
    vb := reflect.ValueOf(b)
    if vb.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        return errors.New("b is not a pointer")
    }
    // vb is a pointer, indirect it to get the
    // underlying value, and make sure it is a struct.
    vb = vb.Elem()
    if vb.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return errors.New("b is not a struct")
    }
    for i := 0; i < vb.NumField(); i++ {
        field := vb.Field(i)
        if field.CanInterface() && IsZeroOfUnderlyingType(field.Interface()) {
            // This field have a zero-value.
            // Search in a for a field with the same name.
            name := vb.Type().Field(i).Name
            fa := va.FieldByName(name)
            if fa.IsValid() {
                // Field with name was found in struct a,
                // assign its value to the field in b.
                if field.CanSet() {
                    field.Set(fa)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

**Output**

```
ua: {ID:1 Username:admin About:I am an admin IsAdmin:true Status:1 Date:2017-05-11 17:47:30.805657327 +0200 CEST}
ub: {ID:0 Username:user About: IsAdmin:false Status:0 Date:<nil>}

ua: {ID:1 Username:admin About:I am an admin IsAdmin:true Status:1 Date:2017-05-11 17:47:30.805657327 +0200 CEST}
ub: {ID:1 Username:user About:I am an admin IsAdmin:true Status:1 Date:2017-05-11 17:47:30.805657327 +0200 CEST}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I will check your code and vote if I solve my problem. thanks again!

Comment: Your welcome. I think the code are enough for you to understand, but if I were you, I would take a closer look to the reflect package.

Comment: I love you, you are very enthusiastic

Answer (score -1):

If I correctly understand what you are going to accomplish, you should better use pointers to objects instead of objects.

For example,

```
A := &User{1,"admin", "I am a admin",status: 1,....}
if A != nil {
  fmt.Println(A)
} else {
  fmt.Println("nil object")
}
```

There is not reason to check if fields of the object are default values.

Comment: Sorry. Only a few fields are default values